# White labelling Enterprise iOS application

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I had developed 3 applications for my client. Now he wants to distribute it to other organizations (doing same business). Other firms will have minor data and image set changes, other functionalities are same. What is the best approach for distributing this 3 application with the other firms?

**1) One solution I think is to upload this 3 application to each firms apple enterprise account.**

*Prons:*

- UI and functionality can be changed for each apps depends on business
  changes.
- Will have different server and APIs. So data security can be increased.

*Cons:*

- Need to maintain different source codes.
- As firms number increases applications also increases, which can be a form of spamming appStore
  with similar applications.

**2) Another solution is to upload this 3 application to one account and is distributed among other firms.** Need to check any legal issue in doing this. By this server will maintain different database for different Companies and user registered with this company will link to the corresponding database. All other calculation and logic will be handled by the server. iOS application switches image set w.r.t company.

Can I do this by any other approach or which one is the best one. The main idea is to give a contract to another firm by creating a set of users having an extendable validity date and this is maintained by my client.

Thanks in advance and any thought on this is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to this is [Volume Purchase Program for Business](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/)

 provided by Apple. It provides you with a functionality called Custom B2B apps for iOS. You can read the details in this [document.](http://images.apple.com/business/docs/VPP_Business_Guide.pdf)